# Return column name based on condition else return NA

Tags: r, dplyr

```
Name GM01 GM02 GM05
    A 99   0   0
    B 1   70  0
    C 0    0  13
    D 0    1   0
```

I'd like to create a new column 'result' that returns the correct "GM" column name from all the columns that start with "GM" that are greater than or equal to 70 and else return NA (for example in row C)
I have tried this but I don't know to include the else statement to return NA

```
wwtp_catchments$result <-names(wwtp_catchments[2:ncol(wwtp_catchments)])[max.col(  
wwtp_catchments[2:ncol(wwtp_catchments)]    >= 70 )]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `rowSums` to turn `result` values to `NA` when there is no value greater than 70 in the row.

```
cols <- grep('GM', names(wwtp_catchments))
wwtp_catchments$result <- names(wwtp_catchments[cols])[max.col(wwtp_catchments[cols] >= 70)] 
wwtp_catchments$result[rowSums(wwtp_catchments[cols] >= 70) == 0] <- NA

wwtp_catchments

#  Name GM01 GM02 GM05 result
#1    A   99    0    0   GM01
#2    B    1   70    0   GM02
#3    C    0    0   13   <NA>
#4    D    0    1    0   <NA>
```